# Ubuntu (18.04) with NAT on Vmware Fusion

Tags: vmware-fusion

I just installed VMware Fusion 10.1.2 on my macOS 10.13.4 and created a new VM using the Ubuntu 18.04 server image. The installation completes without issues, the VM boots up normally.

However, I'm not able to get the networking working. I chose the NAT option, there is a network adapter connected to the VM. `ip link list` in the VM gives me

[image: ip link list output]

So I assume, that `ens33` is the virtual interface connected to the host. But it has no IP address assigned. ifconfig:

[image]

On the host machine there is a `vmnet1` and `vmnet8`. Maybe it's worth noting that I'm also running Docker For Mac.

How can I configure Fusion / the VM so that it gets a usable interface with an IP address and a default gateway etc?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the same macOS and fusion versions, although I installed Ubuntu 18.04 desktop. I got it to work by going to the Settings -> Network and selecting AutoDetect in the Bridged Networking section.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this really is a solution or just some coincendence. I used the `ip addr add` command to manually ad an ip address (from the 192.168.8.0/25 network `vmnet8`). That worked, I could access the internet. After rebooting the VM I even have routes and name resolution, everything works as expexted.